# Tikz - Connection between matrices' entries

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I had draw with `tikz` two matrices (two column array) with this code:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert={outext=.svg,command=\unexpanded{pdf2svg \infile\space\outfile}},multi=false]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1.5cm]
    \matrix (N) [% 
      matrix of nodes, 
      nodes={
        rectangle,
        minimum height=6mm,
        minimum width=15mm,
        anchor=center,
        inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt
      }
    ] at (3, 0) { $\$_0\$_0\$_0$  \\ $AC\$_1$ \\ $TC\$_2$ \\ $ACA$ \\ $\$_2GA$ \\ $\$_0TA$ \\ $\$_1TA$ \\ $CAC$ \\ $CAC$ \\ $GAC$ \\ $TAC$ \\ $TAC$ \\ $CTC$ \\ $C\$_2G$ \\ $\$_0\$_0T$ \\ $C\$_1T$ \\ $ACT$ \\  };
    \draw (N-1-1.north west) rectangle (N-17-1.south east);
    \node[above=3pt of N-1-1]{$Node$};
    
    \matrix (W) [% 
      matrix of nodes, 
      nodes={
        rectangle,
        minimum height=6mm,
        minimum width=9.5mm,
        anchor=center,
        inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt
      }
    ] at (6, 0) { $T$ \\ $T$ \\ $G$ \\ $C$ \\ $C$ \\ $C$ \\ $C^-$ \\ $\$_3$ \\ $\$_1$ \\ $A$ \\ $T$ \\ $A^-$ \\ $\$_2$ \\ $A$ \\ $A$ \\ $A$ \\ $C$ \\  };
    \draw (W-1-1.north west) rectangle (W-17-1.south east);
    \node[above=3pt of W-1-1]{$W$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But, how can I draw connection between their entries?

## Edit

If I use this `\draw (N-1-1) -- (W-5-1);` to connect entries this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Just use something like `\draw (N-1-1) -- (W-5-1);`. You may want to reduce the minimal width of nodes in matrix named `W`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I have already tried with this solution but it is not clear where the 'edge' starts and where it arrives.

Comment: The "edge" starts from and arrives at the node border, which can be drawn by `nodes={..., draw}`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I edit my question with your suggestion. Now you can see that it is not clear where the 'edge' starts and where it arrives

Comment: Please add a sketch of the expected result, so we can give you the help you need. As I already answered to your previous question, you may have noticed that nodes have anchors you can use. For example, try `\draw (N-1-1.east) -- (W-5-1.west)` and you'll get a very different result.

Comment: The "edge" is part of a line `(N-1-1.center) -- (W-5-1.center)`, which starts at the intersection of the line and the border of node `N-1-1`, and ends at the intersection of the line and the border of node `W-5-1`. By adding `nodes={..., draw=blue}` to matrix `N` and `nodes={..., draw=red}` to matrix `M`, you can see the relationship clearer. Since for matrix `M` you set `node={..., minimum width=9.5mm, ...}`, the node border is far beyond the text border, which might cause confusing. That's why I suggest "reduce the minimal width of nodes in matrix named `W`" in my first comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\draw ([xshift=-0.1cm] N-1-1.east) to[out=0, in=180] ([xshift=0.1cm] W-5-1.west);
```

[image: Two nodes connected]